# Pig: Why we can set PARALLEL to ORDER operator

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig

I've read the documentation of [Pig Cookbook](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/cookbook.html#Use+the+PARALLEL+Clause), it says that

```
PARALLEL only affects the number of reduce tasks. Map parallelism is determined by the input file, one map for each HDFS block.
```

I don't understand how `ORDER` can set the number of reducers, I think to get the total sort, ultimately we have to use only 1 reducer to take all the intermediate results and merge, what does the parameter `PARALLEL` refer to?

Answer (score 0):

It works, as the reducers get the data partitioned on key in such a way that keys handled by reducer N are >= keys handled by N-1.

For this, Pig does the sampling followed by partitioning for ORDER. It samples first few records of the input and sees the distribution of ordering key. Based on this sample,  it then builds a partitioner that produces a balanced total order. 
e.g. is we are ordering on a field with the values a, b, c, c, c, c, e, e, e, m, n, o, q, r, z, and if we have three reducers, partitioner would partition the records with fields a-c going to reducer 1, e - m goes to reducer 2, and n-z go to reducer3. 
Each reducer then sorts the data locally yielding globally sorted data.

Comment: What about strings? It's sorted by dictionary order but you can calculate its hash key using different method, so the order of key may not conform with the order of dictionary, this case if you sort it locally you won't automatically get the globally sorted data.

Comment: thats the key. order of the key is same as order of dictionary.

Comment: No it's not the same. Order of dictionary only has relative meaning because string can be arbitrary long while hash value is fixed length integer, even a perfect hash to a 64-bit integer can only order string with no more than 14 characters

Comment: I guess I did not understand your first comment. Anyways, the point is whole key is used to decide the partitioning algorithm for ORDER operation. So its made sure to send the semi-ordered data across reducers for local ordering.